# Join filters with INFORMATICA

Tags: join, filter, informatica

In my Informatica mapping I have two filters.

I would like to join them with a full join Joiner transformation.

Power Center doesn't let me link the columns from the 2 filter transformations.

I can see that when the join is for filter and SQ, it's OK..

But I can't join the source, I have a filter on it and after the filters I need to join..

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: are you joining filters from the same SQ? can you post screenshots of your mapping?

Comment: To join 2 pipelines coming from the same SQ, you have to enable "Sorted Input" in the properties of the Joiner. This also means that data MUST me sorted on the join key or the Joiner will fail during the run.